# Cups in boxes- Probability of choosing a box with no cup broken

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose there are 4 boxes of cups, each box having 3 cups and also given that 5 cups are broken. What is the probability of choosing a box with no cup broken in that box ?

I tried using conditional probability i.e. if A is the event of choosing a box with no cup broken then

P(A)=P(A|5 cups distributed in 2 boxes)+P(A|5 cups distributed in 3 boxes)+ P(A|5 cups distributed in 4 boxes)

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here. Is there any easier method to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Tricky problem.  Believe it or not, WLOG, you choose the 1st box.

Number of ways that 5 broken cups can be distributed into 12 slots is

$$D = \binom{12}{5}.$$

Number of ways that 5 broken cups can be distributed into the 9 slots of the other 3 boxes is

$$N = \binom{9}{5}.$$

Final answer

$$\frac{N}{D}.$$

**Addendum**

First of all, with the original problem as stated, the analysis of $\frac{\binom{9}{5}}{\binom{12}{5}}$ will apply regardless of which box you choose.  Once you choose a box, the question is whether any of the 3 slots in your box will receive a broken cup.

As for your hypothetical:

> Suppose there are 4 boxes of cups with 3 cups in 3 boxes and 2 cups in one box such that 5 cups are broken.

With this hypothetical, I would take the following approach.

If I choose a box with 3 cups, my chance of no broken cup, for reasons similar to the start of my answer, will be

$$\frac{\binom{8}{5}}{\binom{11}{5}}.$$

If I happen to choose the box with 2 cups, my chance of no broken cup will be

$$\frac{\binom{9}{5}}{\binom{11}{5}}.$$

My chance of choosing the box with 2 cups is $\frac{1}{4}.$

Therefore, my answer to the hypothetical would be

$$\left[\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{\binom{9}{5}}{\binom{11}{5}}\right] ~+~
\left[\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{\binom{8}{5}}{\binom{11}{5}}\right].$$

Comment: There has to be some dependency on choosing a box right ? Although it seems there is no effect for given question, but what if one of the box had only 2 cups ?

Comment: @GaneshGani Your hypothetical is contrary to the statement in the query:"Suppose there are 4 boxes of cups, each box having 3 cups"

Comment: I meant, I needed an argument as to why the WLOG part holds here or atleast an argument that would show how the effect of choosing a box is a factor for the overall probability. For instance, if the question was "Suppose there are 4 boxes of cups with 3 cups in 3 boxes and 2 cups in one box such that 5 cups are broken. What is the probability of choosing a box with no cup broken in that box ?". Then the above argument may not work.

Comment: @GaneshGani See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: I guess that should work. Thank you :)